# Perl Regex using qr//

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I'm making a module that parses a text file, and everything I'm trying to match has a `#` in front of it but when I try to use `qr//` it doesn't match anything. The big catch here, at least for me, is that I need it to cycle through the array and I don't think I can use `$1` or it's not working properly. And `%$hash_ref` is information pulled out of a database where the keys are the columns and the values are the values (obviously). The text file has words like `#C3_WK_PH` and `#SPECIAL_NOTES`.

```
sub replace {   
    open (my $in,  '<', "file.txt")  or die "cannot open $in: $!";
    open (my $out, '>', "file2.txt") or die "cannot open $out: $!";

    while (<$in>)
    {
            my @values = values %$hash_ref;
            my @keys   = keys %$hash_ref;
            my $count  = @keys;

            while ($count > 0) {
                my $thing  = $keys[$count];
                my $regexp = qr/#($thing)/;
                s/$regexp/$values[$count]/g;
                $count = $count - 1;
            }
            print $out $_;
    }
            close $in;
            close $out;
}
```

I know that I'm parsing each line `$count` times, but that is intended.

Comment: Parentheses have special meaning in regular expressions. If you want to match a pattern literally, take a look at [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or at [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) specifically the \Q and \E flags.

Comment: Creating the `@values` and `@keys` arrays seems like an astounding amount of extra work/memory. Particularly as you are recreating them for each iteration of the `while` loop.  Have you considered `foreach my $thing (keys %$hash_ref)` and replacing `$values[$count]` with `$hash_ref->{$thing}`?

Comment: What kind of values are you getting in `$thing`? If you just do `s/#$thing/$values[$count]/g;` does that work?

Comment: Can you give us a minimal example of what might be in %hash_ref and what might be in file.txt so we can actually try some stuff?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - I would recommend `\Q` and `\E` over `quotemeta`.  The latter escapes *all* non-word characters, special or not.

Comment: What *exactly* are you getting? You say it doesn't match anything but then you say the big catch is you can't use `$1` - is the problem that it isn't matching or that you're having difficulty using `$1`?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't asking you to walk me through the code, I was asking for example data. What *are* the *values*?

Comment: KEYS:
C1_NAME
C2_WK_PH
CUSTOM_LOCATION
C2_DEPT
C1_WK_PH
MSDS_LOCATION
C2_NAME
C2_OFFICE
SPECIAL_NOTES
C1_HM_PH
C1_DEPT
LAST_UPDATE
NOTES
C2_HM_PH
C3_HM_PH
C1_OFFICE
C3_WK_PH
C3_DEPT2
The values are personal information, just text.
The text file contains the keys as placeholders except have a # infront of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problems don't have anything to do with `qr//`. 
Arrays in Perl are 0-indexed, so the first time through your `while ($count > 0) ...` loop:

```
        my $thing = $keys[$count];
```

sets `$thing` to `undef` because the largest element of `@keys` is `$count-1`

```
        my $regexp = qr/#($thing)/;
```

sets `$regexp` to `qr/#()/`, and

```
        s/$regexp/$values[$count]/g;
```

erases all the `#` characters from your input, replaces them with nothing, and renders the rest of your intended substitutions pointless.

If you were using `use warnings`, you would have gotten a hint about the problem.

Writing your loop as `while ($count-- > 0) ...` would work (and also make sure you process the values in `$keys[0]` and `$values[0]`), but consider a more Perl-y way of iterating through your hash:

```
foreach my $thing (keys %$hashref) {
    my $replace = $hashref->{$thing};
    ...
}

while (my ($thing,$replace) = each %$hashref) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am using warnings but I didn't get any runtime errors. I always use warnings and strict, like a good boy should.

Comment: Wouldn't the while be more efficient to use?

Answer (score 2):

This is simplified a bit from what you've got, but it should give the right idea:

```
%hash = ( 'f' => 'foo', 'b' => 'bar', 'c' => 'chimp' );
replace();

sub replace {   
    open (my $in, '<', "file.txt") or die "cannot open $in: $!";
    while (<$in>)
    {
            foreach my $thing (keys %hash) {
            s/#($thing)/$hash{$thing}/g;
            #print;
            }
            print;
    }
    close $in;
}
```

With that code I was able to successfully transform text with #f and #b and #c into text with foo and bar and chimp.

Moving back to the hash reference, I have this code which once again seems to be working fine. (I've left the trace statements in this time.)

```
%hash = ( 'f' => 'foo', 'b' => 'bar', 'c' => 'chimp' );
$hash_ref = \%hash;
replace();

sub replace {   
    open (my $in, '<', "file.txt") or die "cannot open $in: $!";
    while (<$in>)
    {
            foreach my $thing (keys %{$hash_ref}) {
            #my $regexp = qr/#($thing)/;
print "REPLACING $thing WITH ${$hash_ref}{$thing}\nBEFORE: $_";
            s/#($thing)/${$hash_ref}{$thing}/g;
print "AFTER: $_";
            }
            print;
    }
    close $in;
}
```

If the `${$hash_ref}{$thing}` syntax isn't working for you then you'll need to tell us how you're creating your `$hash_ref` because that syntax is working fine here...:

Comment: The only issue I'm getting with this is how can I use my hash ref in the regex? It just recognises the % as bare text and I can't find any solutions on google.

Comment: I'm on my phone now so can't do symbols easily. See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/perl-hash-reference/

Comment: I think ${$hashref}{$thing}